# How to pass value in URL in django-restframework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have been following below tutorial and it's just showing value in POSTMAN

https://dzone.com/articles/create-a-simple-api-using-django-rest-framework-in

Code:

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def IdealWeight(heightdata):
    try:
        height=json.loads(heightdata.body)
        weight=str(height*10)
        return JsonResponse("Ideal weight should be:"+weight+" kg",safe=False)
    except ValueError as e:
        return Response(e.args[0],status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I want to use GET method instead of POST and pass value of height in url,
example: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/IdealWeight/height=20`

and result should be visible in the form of JSON

Comment: It seems the tutorial is a bit outdated and not using *proper Python conventions* as well as DRFs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get value from url using `query_params`

Try this:

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def IdealWeight(request):   
    try:      
        height= int(request.query_params.get('height'))
        weight=(height)*10
        return JsonResponse({"Weight should be": "{}".format(weight)}, status=status. HTTP_200_OK)
    except ValueError as e:
        return Response(e.args[0],status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Type below URL to get result:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/IdealWeight/?height=20`

Make sure in pass `/` in your urls.py, since you're using GET method:
`path('IdealWeight/',views.IdealWeight,name='IdealWeight'),`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use query params as a medium to pass height in the URL.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/IdealWeight/?height=20
```

Query parameters also called Query string are optional key-value pairs that appear to the right of the ? in a URL.

```
key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3...
```

- Within each pair, the key and value are separated by an equals sign `=`.
- The series of pairs are separated by the ampersand, `&`

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def IdealWeight(request):
    try:
        height=int(request.query_params.get('height', 0))
        weight=str(height*10)
        return JsonResponse("Ideal weight should be:"+weight+" kg",safe=False)
    except ValueError as e:
        return Response(e.args[0],status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```